# I have problems in retrieving data from sharedpreferences of one activity to another activity

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity{

final String defaultPassword = "123456";
Button login, cancel;
EditText input;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.security);

    //SharedPreferences from other Activity
    final String LOGIN_PASSWORD = "Login_Password";
    SharedPreferences loginPassword = getSharedPreferences(LOGIN_PASSWORD, 0);
    final String storedPass = loginPassword.getString("loginPassword", "");

    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {                
            finish();
        }
    });

    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

            String inputPass = input.getText().toString();

            if (!inputPass.equals("")){

                if (storedPass.equals("")){

                    if (inputPass.equals(defaultPassword)){
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ActivateActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        input.setText("");
                    }
                }
                else{

                    if (inputPass.equals(storedPass)){
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ActivateActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Not matched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        input.setText("");
                    }
                }   
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Nothing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                input.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I am designing a login page for accessing the apps, initially when user first use the app, the password is not set, so a default password "123456" is used to access the apps, after user set the password, the default password cannot be used to access the apps... So now I have to retrieve the user set password which stored in another activity shared preferences. So next time when user access the apps, i can compare the user input with the stored password, but how can i achieve this? is it something wrong with my coding?

Comment: where you are setting the value in shared preference?

Comment: @Android_Rookie: When you save the credentials in the other `Activity` are you calling `commit()` on the `SharedPreferences.Editor`? You need to do this or the data won't be saved.

Comment: yes, i did commit in Activity A, but am I can just calling the data in sharedpreferences of Activity A in activity B?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `getSharedPreferences(LOGIN_PASSWORD, 0)`, make sure that `LOGIN_PASSWORD` is the same value in both activities. Otherwise, you are opening two different preferences.

Comment: @Android_Rookie will you edit your question and add where you are setting and retrieving the value for both activities please?